# Azure policy assignment using powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-policy

How to enable two scope levels(resource group and subscription) simultaneously in azure policy using powershell?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot enable two scope levels simultaneously.

You can only define a single scope, but you can define exclusions under it.

If you want a multiple subscriptions you can do it using a **Management Group** as the scope and then exclude those you don't want included.